# Cannot create new spring-servlet.xml file

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc

I deleted my spring-servlet.xml (which was created by selecting "new spring bean configuration file" in Eclipse). When I try to create a new spring-servlet.xml file, Eclipse returns the old spring-servlet.xml file. I have refreshed the project, cleaned it and updated the project but the deleted spring-servlet.xml file is continually returned. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: Can you close Eclipse and edit this file manually and reopen Eclipse?

Comment: Go and see on the disk if the same old file is present. if yes just delete it, refresh the project. It will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

> Delete the target folder of your project,if you are usingspring-mvc with maven

You will see that in target folder all classes and xml files are generated and these are used during runtime of the application.